# Background image CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, transform

We are facing this white space issue (http://take.ms/xuQJS) in following demo specially in Safari?

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZBeMG

We can't find the source of issue, any help is appreciated. Consider that we only want to use `transform` in our animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.scroll` is too short. Try `.scroll {width: 200%}`. Now you have width `100%` and and you move your element -500px, so there will be gap.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scrollGood {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes scrollGood {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0);
  }
}
.pen {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel {
  padding: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #31CC70;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.bottom .scroll {
  background-image: url(http://scarbroughstudios.com/img/codepen.svg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 400%;
  width: 200%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: scrollGood 5s linear infinite;
  animation: scrollGood 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<section class="pen">
<div class="panel bottom">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
</section>
```